# Janrain/Simple Modal under Redirected Domain

Tags: plugins, theme-development, users, redirect, login

I have a wordpress site running on one domain that has the main 'client' domain for the site redirecting to it.  I've got my Wordpress Address/Site Address entered correcting in Wordpress, and the .htaccess is formatted properly afaik.  Everything else seems to work properly other than this issue.

So I have Janrain Engage, SimpleModal Jainrain Engage and SimpleModal Login.  Everything was working fine when we were building the site on the hosted domain.  When it came time to switch the live sites and redirect the published URL to our host, things went all screwy.

So, basically;

If you go to www.publishedurl.com and attempt to login with your Wordpress user/pass the loggin in progress bar appears and just hangs indefinitely.  If you try and loging with your Facebook ID it appears to successfully log you in, but on www.publishedurl.com it shows you as not logged in.  If you then go to www.backendurel.com/wordpressinstall/ it will show you logged in with Facebook -- and back there, if you attempt to log-in, that works fine as well.

I've updated Wordpress and the plugins, I've scoured the wp_options table in the database for a setting that might be wrong.  I completely uninstalled and reinstalled everything, created new Jainrain and Facebook widgets.

ATM I have the files and folders of all 3 plugins set to 775 permission.

We also use Mingle and a few other widgets that block users from viewing the WP backend daskboard and allow front-end posting.

PS.  Actually, during the course of this whole re-install I've now broken everything at the www.backendurl.com/wordpressinstall... same action... endless "loggin in" progress bar... had to pull the php redirect off my wp-login page... ugg.. help please! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try [this fix](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-simplemodal-login-does-not-redirect-to-anything?replies=5#post-1860427) and see if it resolved your issue?

Comment: Our issue had to do with the host we were using. but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Our issue had to do with our host and the limited capabilities of their servers.  We moved everything to a new account where our client had originally registered his domain (hostgator) and it worked great.